# How can I improve speed of OPi.GPIO on Orange Pi Zero?

Tags: python, gpio, orange-pi

I am working on Orange Pi Zero. I control consecutive GPIO 3 and got the signal on the logical state like this

```py
    import OPi.GPIO as GPIO

    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    GPIO.setup(15, GPIO.OUT)

    GPIO.output(15, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(15, GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(15, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(15, GPIO.HIGH)
    .
    .
    GPIO.output(15, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(15, GPIO.HIGH)
```

[image]
  The result on Saleae logic viewer

1. Why the period decrease?
2. The maximum frequency is about 2khz and how can I improve it?